# Printing string representations of xattr hex output

Tags: macos, formatting, xattr

I'm trying to write a script to extract the original download URL from disk images downloaded with Safari on OS X using xattr, so that I can rename them but still easily obtain their original names for reference.

This command prints the hex representation of the URL that the given file was downloaded from, as an example:

```
xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms *.dmg
```

gives

```
62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 5F 10 4F 68 74 74
70 3A 2F 2F 61 64 63 64 6F 77 6E 6C 6F 61 64 2E
61 70 70 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 4D 61 63 5F 4F 53
5F 58 2F 6D 61 63 5F 6F 73 5F 78 5F 31 30 2E 36
2E 31 5F 62 75 69 6C 64 5F 31 30 62 35 30 34 2F
30 34 31 35 30 37 33 61 2E 64 6D 67 08 0A 00 00
00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5C
```

The URL starts at the 14th byte (if I counted correctly) and is NULL terminated. How can I format this string so that I get a string output as follows:

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Mac_OS_X/mac_os_x_10.6.1_build_10b504/0415073a.dmg

*(don't worry, this link doesn't work unless you're logged in to ADC)*

...essentially, the same thing Finder will display in Get Info. I tried piping xattr's output to xxd but I'm not sure how to specify the offset so the string starts at the right place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after looking at the binary data returned by xattr -p, I realized that it was actually a binary plist... hence "bplist" at the front of the data. For some reason I didn't notice this before, but in light of this, here's a proper solution that should work on every OS X from 10.5 to 10.8.

To avoid duplication, I'll link to the source instead of pasting it: https://github.com/jakepetroules/wherefrom